# center a with text-align: left in a fixed-width div

Tags: css, wordpress

I have to build a navbar in wordpress, that looks like that: each li has `width: 80px`, and the a is centered in it, but the text in the a has `text-align: left;` property.

Hope that was clear enough...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to text-align left the a, unless you set them to display block, in which case there is no sense to make li align center, and a align left!

Maybe you mean center the whole nav, but have the links be align left? In that case this is how you do it:

**Demo** http://jsbin.com/ezuloz/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the demo, it helped me for another problem... but it's not what I meant. I need to center the `<a>` in the `<li width="80">`. I don't know what the width of the <a> is, and can't do `a{ text-align: center; }` because the text has to be left-aligned.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the `<a>` element to have a block display, you can then set a width and margin so that it will center.

Here's a link to [an example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanosha/4xgjJ/).

```
a {
  text-align:left;
  display:block;
  width:40px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I DON'T know what is the `<a>` width, that is exactly the problem....
The only width I know is the `<li>`'s. the `<a>` has to be centered in it, but the text in the `<a>` should have `text-align: left`.